# Proxy in selenium python doesn't change my ip

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use a Proxy in selenium python, but when i test the code on a web page that show my ip the proxy doesn't change my ip adress.

Here there is the code

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


option = Options()
driver = uc.Chrome(options = option)

PROXY = "139.162.214.146"

option.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
option.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
option.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
option.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
option.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
option.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
option.add_argument('--mute-audio')
option.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
option.add_argument('--disable-logging')

driver.get("https://www.whatismyip.com/")

input ()
```

The code should change mi ip but this doesn't appen, i tried to change the proxy but the problem is the same.

Comment: move this line of code `driver = uc.Chrome(options = option)` after all the `add_argument` statements. also you would need to provide `port` too.

Answer (score 0):

I can see multiple issues here. Try using the following code:

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


option = Options()

PROXY = "139.162.214.146"

option.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
option.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
option.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
option.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
option.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
option.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
option.add_argument('--mute-audio')
option.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
option.add_argument('--disable-logging')

driver = uc.Chrome(options = option)

driver.get("https://www.whatismyip.com/")

input ()
```

Also note, that you need to specify a port for your proxy as following: `PROXY = "139.162.214.146:proxy_port"`